# i want to redirect the my all webpage url

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

is any possible way to rewrite my all webpage url. For example i was create a webpage name index.aspx and Event_view.aspx. It show in the address bar something like this..

```
http://localhost:65232/HRM/user/index.aspx
http://localhost:65232/HRM/user/Event_view.aspx
```

I want to convert the above url to something like this  http://localhost:65232/HRM/user/sdf-3434sd34-343243-@45_343/Event_view

please help me to redirect the webpage url..

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Everyone wants his URLs to be as clean as possible, but you want to make them more complicated? What would that "sdf-3434sd34344243-@45-343" stand for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use URLRewrite module. The below link will give you a good walkthrough

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-implement-url-rewriting

http://dotnetguts.blogspot.in/2008/07/url-rewriting-with-urlrewriternet.html

Comment: am using a href to redirect the page.

Comment: if that is the case why not write a small utility that scans all the pages and replace it?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using IIS 7 you can use "rewrite http module", or write your own httpmodule to rewrite the url.

if using iis 6 you can create an isapi.dll by c++ or python or write your own httpmodule to rewrite the url and host it in your web.config

take a look at [here](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Create-Http-Module.aspx)